# Why is tabu package reading what is inside \begin{htmlonly} tags?

Tags: tabu, latex2html

I think there is a bug here.

### Introduction

I use `latex2html` (L2H) to build some HTML Pages from LaTeX. The standard method to add L2H specific latex command is like this

```
\begin{htmlonly}
   % for L2H eyes only
\end{htmlonly}
```

This has been working fine for years.  Hence the method to build the same LaTeX document with L2H and with pdfLaTeX is to do this

```
\documentclass{article}%
\usepackage{html}
\usepackage{ifpdf}
\begin{document}

\begin{htmlonly}
  %l2h only
\end{htmlonly}

%\begin{latexonly}    % WARNING, SPECIAL COMMENT DO NOT REMOVE
 \ifpdf
     %for pdflatex only
  \fi
%\end{latexonly}      % WARNING, SPECIAL COMMENT DO NOT REMOVE

\end{document}
```

and now I can do `pdflatex foo.tex` and do `latex2html foo.tex` and both are happy.

### Problem when using tabu package

Now I wanted to use `tabu` package in pdfLaTeX only. So I used the above set up and wrote

```
\documentclass{article}%
\usepackage{html}
\usepackage{ifpdf}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tabu}
\begin{document}

\begin{htmlonly}
 \begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
\end{htmlonly}

%\begin{latexonly}       % WARNING, SPECIAL COMMENT DO NOT REMOVE
 \ifpdf
   \begin{longtabu}{|l|l|}
  \fi
%\end{latexonly}

a&b\\
c&d\\

\begin{htmlonly}
  \end{tabular}
\end{htmlonly}

%\begin{latexonly}   % WARNING, SPECIAL COMMENT DO NOT REMOVE
\ifpdf
  \end{longtabu}
\fi
%\end{latexonly}

\end{document}
```

and now when I do   `pdflatex t9.tex` I get this error:

```
(./t9.out) (./t9.out)
! Misplaced alignment tab character &.
<argument>  \fi \par a&
                       b\\ c&d\\ \par \par \begin {htmlonly} 
l.22   \end{tabular}
```

Which means `tabu` is looking at the `tabular` env. But this environment should never been seen by `tabu`.

Compare the above now, when I just use `longtable`. No `tabu` now. It works:

```
\documentclass{article}%
\usepackage{html}
\usepackage{ifpdf}
\usepackage{longtable,tabu}

\begin{document}

\begin{htmlonly}
 \begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
\end{htmlonly}

%\begin{latexonly}   % WARNING, SPECIAL COMMENT DO NOT REMOVE
 \ifpdf
   \begin{longtable}{|l|l|}
  \fi
%\end{latexonly}

a&b\\
c&d\\

\begin{htmlonly}
  \end{tabular}
\end{htmlonly}

%\begin{latexonly}  % WARNING, SPECIAL COMMENT DO NOT REMOVE
\ifpdf
   \end{longtable}
\fi
%\end{latexonly}

\end{document}
```

and now no error

```
>pdflatex t9.tex 
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (TeX Live 2012/Debian)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
.....
Output written on t9.pdf (1 page, 10799 bytes).
Transcript written on t9.log.
>
```

**question is:**  why is `tabu` reading my `htmlonly` code?

I need to use `longtabu` since I read it can make longtable with same settings as `tabularx` which I needed.

I am using  (TeX Live 2012/Debian) on Linux mint 14.

Comment: I don't think there's tex4ht compatibility code for `tabu` as there is for other packages.

Comment: You should nest the parts correctly: Move the htmlonly `\end{tabular}` behind the  `\end{longtabu}`. Currently the htmlonly `\end{tabular}` is (quite unnecessarly) inside a cell and this is quite dangerous - even with less complex tabular commands then the one provided by tabu (you would get similar problems e.g. with amsmath tabulars).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like you can hide the inner tabular code like this:

```
\relax\iffalse{\fi
\begin{htmlonly}
  \end{tabular}
\end{htmlonly}
\relax\iffalse}\fi
```

Answer (score 4):

Well, since you ask "why", there are 2 reasons I believe:

1. Package `tabu` pre-reads its contents and stores them somewhere before executing them. This makes the contents more like a macro argument than an envrionment contents. I'm not sure whether `{htmlonly}` environment can be used in macro arguments without any problems.
2. As **egreg** points out, `latex2html` uses its own tweaks for various problematic environment (floats, tables, etc.) and there's obviously no such tweak done for `tabu`. You can propose a feature request to the maintainer of `latex2html`, since `tabu` is not much different from any other table-making environment, it should not be such a problem.